# Return only working first time in function

Tags: python, function, return

When I run my rock paper scissors game in python, and spell one of `'rock'`, `'paper'`, or `'scissors'` wrong on purpose, as expected it runs the `Player_num` function again. However when I then enter the correctly spelled choice, it returns number it returns it as a `NoneType`; whereas if I spell it correctly on the first time, it returns the variable number as an `int` not a `NoneType`.

I cannot figure out how to fix this, I have tried tracing the variables, but I have got no luck.

```
#Part of rock paper scissors game
def Player_num():
    #Player chooses one of rock paper or scissors
    print("Choose 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors' by typing that word. ")
    guess = input()
    #The if statement is to decide whether the user's input is right or not
    if Valid_guess(guess):
        #if it is right, it continues with the game
        #the user's choice will be converted to a number 1,2 or 3
        if guess == 'rock':
            number = 1
        elif guess == 'paper':
            number = 2
        elif guess == 'scissors':
            number = 3
        return number
        #if the input is invalid, the system prompts the user to try it again
    else:
        print('That response is invalid.')
        Player_num()

#Part of rock paper scissors game
def Valid_guess(guess):
    #Validates the user's input
    if guess == 'rock' or guess == 'paper' or guess == 'scissors':
        status = True
    else:
        status = False
    #Returns the boolean value status
    return status
```

Comment: `return guess in {'rock','paper', 'scissors'}` will do what all your code it doing in the function,  You should also use a while loop not keep calling the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your function, in the `else` block, you have written:

```
Player_num()
```

I assume you mean:

```
return Player_num()
```

Otherwise, you get the correct input, but do not return it to the caller. The function instead runs off the end, and returns `None`, the default return value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
def Player_num():
    print("Choose 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors' by typing that word. ")
    guess = input()
    if Valid_guess(guess):
        if guess == 'rock':
            number = 1
        elif guess == 'paper':
            number = 2
        elif guess == 'scissors':
            number = 3
        return number
    else:
        print('That response is invalid.')
        return Player_num()

def Valid_guess(guess):
    if guess in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']:
        return True
    return False
```

`Valid_guess` is simplified into one statement, also.

Comment: If you were going  try to  improve the code it would be better to just return ,`return guess in {'rock','paper', 'scissors'}` and also use a while loop